# Creating a batch file (or something else maybe?) that scans a .txt file and then copies the specified text to another .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I own a small minecraft server, and I would like to create a google spreadsheet for calculating user playtime data. I wan't this data because it would help let me know if my advertising campaigns are working or not. You can try to eyeball this stuff, but a solid data set would be alot more effective than guessing if the advertising is effective. The problem lies in the fact that manually searching for data from the server logs is really hard. I would appreciate anyone who could help me build a simple script or something that reads a .txt file and extracts the data I need. The script needs to be able to:

1. Detect lines with "User Authenticator" and "Disconnected" then print the entire line.
2. Format the text in some way? Possibly alphabetize the lines so that were not all over the place looking for specific users logins and logouts, defeating the purpose of the script. Not sure if this is possible.
3. Exclude lines with certain text (usernames), we want normal player data, not admin data.

I am sorry if did anything wrong, this is my first time on the site.

UPDATE: The admin data would be stored in a file called "admins.txt". By "alphabetizing" i meant it, example: Player A joins at 06:00, Player B joins at 06:30, then, Player A leaves at 06:45, Player B leaves at 07:00. If the data was flat, it would end up reading something like: A: 6:00, B: 6:30, A:6:45, B:7:00. But I would rather it be: A: 6:00, A: 6:45, B: 6:30, B: 7:00. That would make it easier to chart it out and make a calculation. Sorry for the long text.

Also typical server logging looks like this:
[15:46:30] [User Authenticator #1/INFO]: UUID of player DraconicPiggy is (UUID)

[15:46:31] [Server thread/INFO]: DraconicPiggy[/(Ip address)] logged in with entity id 157 at ([world]342.17291451961574, 88.0, -32.04791955684438)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following awk script will report only on the two line types that you mentioned.

```
/User Authenticator|Disconnected/ {
    print
}
```

I'm guessing "alpabetize" means sort. If so then you can pass the awk output to sort via a pipe.

```
awk -f script.awk | sort
```

I'm assuming the file is a log that's already in date-time sequence, with the timestamps at the start of the line. In this case you'll need to tell sort what to sort on.`sort /?` will tell you how to do this.

### Multiple input files

To process all log files in the current directory use:

```
awk -f script.awk *.log
```

### Redirect output to file

The simplest way is by adding `> filtered.log` to the command, like this:

```
awk -f script.awk *.log > filtered.log
```

That will filter all the input files into a single output file. If you need to write one filtered log for each input file then a minor script change is needed:

```
/User Authenticator|Disconnected/ {
    print >> FILENAME ".filtered.log"
}
```

### Filtering admins and redirecting to several files

The admins file should be similar to this:

```
Admin
DarkAdmin
PinkAdmin
```

The admin names must not contain spaces. i.e `DarkAdmin` is OK, but `Dark Admin` woud not work. Similarly the user names in your log files must **not** contain spaces for this script to work.
Execute the following script with this command:

`awk -f script.awk admins.txt *.log`

Probably best to make sure the log files and the filtered output are in separate directories.

```
NR == FNR {
  admins[ $1 ] = NR
  next
}

/User Authenticator|Disconnected/ {
  if ( $8 in admins ) next
  print >> FILENAME ".filtered.log"
}
```

The above script will:

- Ignore all lines that mention an admin.
- Creat a filtered version of every log file. i.e. if there are 5 log files then 5 filtered logs will be created.

### Sorting the output

You have two sort keys in the file, the user and the time. This is beyone the capabilities of the standard Windows sort program, which seens very primitive. Yo should be able to do it with Gnu Sort:

`sort --stable --key=8 test.log > sorted_test.log`

Where:

- `--key=8` tells it to sort on field 8 (user)
- `--stable` keeps the files in date order within each user

Example of sorting a log file and displaying the result:

```
terry@Envy:~$ sort --stable --key=8 test.log
[15:23:30] [User Authenticator #1/INFO]: UUID of player Doris is (UUID)
[16:36:30] [User Disconnected #1/INFO]: UUID of player Doris is (UUID)
[15:46:30] [User Authenticator #1/INFO]: UUID of player DraconicPiggy is (UUID)
[16:36:30] [User Disconnected #1/INFO]: UUID of player DraconicPiggy is (UUID)
[10:24:30] [User Authenticator #1/INFO]: UUID of player Joe is (UUID)
terry@Envy:~$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218857/discussion-on-answer-by-terry-ebdon-creating-a-batch-file-or-something-else-may).